# Using a Func with a DI Service for Automapper to resolve a value

Tags: c#, automapper

My current configuration for AutoMapper uses [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) dependency resolve to resolve services. The object resolving the services isn't important to the point of the question, but the fact that something is resolving services is.

```
var mapper = new MapperConfiguration((cfg) =>
{
  cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => DependencyResolver.GetService(type);

  // mappings...
});
```

At the moment I'm using both [TypeConveters](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters) and [ValueResolvers](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers) to resolve properties but sometimes it seems like it's way overkill.  For example:

```
public class CarDO // Data Object
{
  public int CarId { get; set; }
  public int OwnerId { get; set; }
}

public class CarBO // Business Object
{
  public int OwnerId { get; set; }
  public string OwnerName { get; set; }
}

public class UsersBL // Business Layer
{
  public strung GetName(int userId) { return userNameFromId } // example
}

public class CarBL
{
  public CarBO Get(int carId)
  {
     var carDO = _repositoryDataAccessWhatever.GetCar(carId);

     var result = mapper.Map<CarBO>(carDO);

     return result;
  }
}
```

Normally I'd have to create an entire object to resolve the OwnerName (and this is a bad example, because this would be a good candidate for reuse, but lets assume it isn't).

```
public class UserNameResolver : ValueResolver<CarDO, string>
{
  private readonly IUserBL _userBL;

  public UserNameResolver(IUserBL userBL)
  {
    _userBl = userBL;  // DI by DependencyResolver Configured Above
  }

  protected override int ResolveCore(CarDO carDO)
  {
    var result = _userBL.GetUserName(carDO.UserId);

    return result;
  }
}
```

then Map it:

```
cfg.CreateMap<CarDO, CarBO>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, 
    opt => opt.ResolveUsing<UserNameResolver >());
```

To me that seems like a overkill.  I looked through the docs and I'm hoping I missed something simple like (this doesn't work obviously):

```
cfg.CreateMap<CarDO, CarBO>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, 
    opt => opt.MapFrom<IUserBL>((do, userBL) => 
    {
      return userBL.GetUserName(do.UserId);
    }));
```

Is there an extension method that allows Func with DI or some other pattern that doesn't require a TypeConverter or ValueResolver?